# STM32 li-ion battery voltage level watch

Tags: voltage, batteries, stm32, adc, feedback

[image]I am using STM32 ADC and voltage divider to measure 4S li-ion battery level. When I connect the Raspberry Pi supply to the buck regulator, it measures 0.4 V incorrectly at the voltage level I measured. When I turn off the Raspberry Pi, I measure the voltage level correctly. Is the problem caused by the regulator I am using or what can be done to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Do all blocks in your diagram share ground?

Comment: yes, sure all ground has shared

Comment: What is the capacity of the battery?

Comment: Also a 2s Li-Ion battery would be 8.4V, maybe a typo.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of your actual circuit - your diagram is very basic and does not show us the full picture.

Comment: my battery is lion 8.4V 12000mah. I have added the power circuit picture.  Actually, I have another problem, the regulator output voltage level decreases as the input voltage level decreases. (For example, 8.4 V input-output 5.8V @1.2Amper, Input 7.5V output 5.3V ..)

Comment: Please share your full schematic. Have you tested the voltage regulator by itself?

Comment: yes ı have tested, it works properly